# Expression engine style url segments with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine

Good day folks,

Recently I worked with EE and was quite impressed with they small but flexible url segment feature.

So I though it will be useful in JS development and what to hear your thoughts and ideas how it can be done.

Who don't know, here is little explanation:

EE url segment is used to compare url part value after each "/" and they have segment1 "/" that is main url part value after domain name, segment2 "/../" that is next url part value and etc.

Why I am interested in it?

I want to create one JS file and call for parts in it only on pages I want.

For example if first url segment is empty I will call for JS that is for home page.

If first url segment is /contact I will call JS for contact page (validation, etc.).

If second segment is /get-to-us (/contact/get-to-us) I will call only JS for google map, etc.

So, the question is, how to take and compare segments with jQuery.

P.S. Explanation on EE website http://expressionengine.com/wiki/URL_Segment_Variables/

Answer (score 1):

This seems like far more work than you need to do. Why not just load distinct JS files conditionally in your template?

```
{if segment_1 == 'contact' && segment_2 == ''}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/validation.js"></script>
{/if}

{if segment_1 == 'contact' && segment_2 == 'get-to-us'}
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/map.js"></script>
{/if}
```

Etc...

I know this doesn't answer your specific question, but it seems like the cheaper way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with D-Rock. The idea to dynamically pull in JavaScript based on the URL seems like a lot of work for very little return on investment — not to mention increasing the complexity and maintenance of the site.

However, to accomplish your goal, there are a few ways to approach this:

- Embed the JavaScript for the current URL into that page's template (no conditionals needed, though not all of your JavaScript is in one place).
- Reference a site-wide embed/snippet on every page, then use conditionals to show only what you need (as suggested by D-Rock).

Depending on your needs or requirements, you *may find it easier* to simply include all of your site's JavaScript into a single external file and allow the browser to download and cache the file. This has the benefit of being extremely easy to maintain, and will decrease subsequent page loads (since the browser can load the file from its cache).

However you plan to use conditionals, when choosing between [Simple or Advanced Conditionals](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html), use **simple conditionals before advanced conditionals** — this is a proven [performance recommendation](http://expressionengine.com/blog/entry/troubleshooting_site_performance_issues/).